# Google recaptcha work fine but

Tags: jquery, html, recaptcha

I am trying to check both the checkbox is check or not it works when

1. user select google recaptcha then custom checkbox then my submit button enable
   The problem is that
2. when user select first custom box then google recaptcha that submit button not enable.

My code is:

```
 <div class="container">
            <form action="captcha.php" method="POST">
                <div class="g-recaptcha"data-theme="dark light"  data-sitekey="6LenpCATAAAAAPNX7KmRsznT15ViNFKBI80ieTUU"></div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">
                <p>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
```

[Fiddle with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/cwqto5Lp/)

Answer (score 0):

What about hiding the terms and conditions until recaptcha is complete? I tried your code with two checkboxes as recpatcha won't work unless the fiddle url is included in your recaptcha settings on google.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').attr({disabled: 'disabled'});
    $('#terms').hide();
    $(document).on('click', function(event) {
      enableSubmit();
    });
    $(document).on('change','#g-recaptcha-response', function() {
      enableSubmit();
    });
    function enableSubmit() {
      if($('#g-recaptcha-response').val() !== '') {
        console.log('in if ');
        $('#terms').show();
        if($('#terms').is(':checked')) {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }   
        else 
        {
          console.log('in else ');
          $('#submit').attr({
          disabled: 'disabled'
          });
        }
      }
};
```

two check boxes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit').attr({
                disabled: 'disabled'
            });
    $('#terms1').hide();
            $(document).on('click', function(event) {
                enableSubmit();
            });
            $(document).on('change','#terms', function() {
                enableSubmit();
            });
            function enableSubmit() {
                if($('#terms').is(':checked')) {
                    console.log('in if ');
        $('#terms1').show();
        if($('#terms').is(':checked') && $('#terms1').is(':checked')) {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }   
                } else {
                    console.log('in else ');
                    $('#submit').attr({
                        disabled: 'disabled'
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: you have used two checkboxs so it is possible to check .is(':checked') but when you try this with google recaptcha we don't have checkbox there and you can not check weather it is checked or not

Comment: Ah i see, I was thinking document.on.change wouldstill fire the enableSubmit function since the result value is changing?

Comment: It will not fire change event so button will not enable